# Undeserved chat suspension

Tags: support, chat

So this just happened:

[image: suspension]

[This](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/28093955/history) is the linked message. For those that can't see it, the text was "I want that in my mouth".

I was talking about food. Specifically, [the previous message](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28093936#28093936):

[image]

Does somebody have a grudge? Was it an accident? Did cosmic rays hit the servers just right to cause that?

Comment: You joke about the cosmic rays, but that's actually a greater [security concern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aT7mnSstKGs) than most people think ;-)

Comment: Looks inappropriate to me. What does it have to do with code golf, programming puzzles, or any on-topic subject?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Granted, in general there's a significant difference between inappropriate content, which warrants flags, and off topic content, which is simply irrelevant to the site.

Comment: @AlexA., I was being slightly facetious, but if a few more suspensions were dished out for rambling off-topic chat then the 19th hole might not have ended up with a signal-to-noise ratio which seemed to be around 1% the last time I was there.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Assuming you weren't being facetious again just now, off-topic chatter isn't deserving of a suspension; rude, inappropriate, or otherwise abusive content and/or conduct is, as is abuse of flags. The Nineteenth Byte has a lot off off-topic content but is generally well behaved in terms of the other things. Things are on topic occasionally, certainly more than 1% of the time, just not 100%.

Answer (score 9):

The immediate context:

> brb changing pants

[This was a reply to the image in the question.]

> (because I drooled all over them, dirty mind)
>   I want that in my mouth

It's not clear what happened, but the message did draw two separate flags. My *guess* is that your previous messages [primed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)) some people to assume you were attempting some sort of crass humor. It took me about three tries to figure out your train of thought. I would imagine the flaggers simply arrived at the wrong conclusion from the way the chat items were [phrased](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyLWrKh2fB0).

So, I guess, in a sense, the chat suspension was undeserved. On the other hand, there's no shame in expressing the idea using a less ambiguous phrase such as:

- Yum!
- That looks delicious.
- I bet that's tasty.

Comment: @Mego: Given my initial misunderstanding of what you were trying to communicate on chat, _I think_ [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) applies here. It's not uncommon for jokes in chat to be a race to the bottom and [flags are signals](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8086/15823) that other people would like to pump the brakes. The message you should take away from this incident is to be a bit more cautious with the double entendre. Blaming the flagger(s) is the wrong action to take here.